# why does matrix balancing improve the linear systems condition number of the eigenvector matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Matrix balancing or diagonal scaling, where at each iteration we choose a diagonal matrix so that the row and column norms are approximately equal (Osborne, 1960, Parlett and Reinsch, 1969, many others), is well known as a strategy to decrease the matrix norm.  In the original Osborne paper, he proves that at every iteration, the matrix norm of his algorithm is non-decreasing.

However, Matlab shows http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/balance.html examples (see second example) where balancing can also improve the linear-systems condition number of the eigenvector matrix.  I'm finding the same thing in my own experiments.  Why does it help with that?  A few equations in particular illustrating why would be much appreciated.